# How to do a join in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    part_number = models.CharField()

class Inventory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    storage_location = ...

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()

class ProjectItem(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

There can be multiple `Inventory` objects for a given part, one for each storage location.  Given a `Project`, I want to get a list of all the `ProjectItem`'s along with the corresponding `Inventory` objects for each `ProjectItem` part.  Is this possible with a Django query?

I could do

```
for pi in ProjectItem.objects.filter(project=project):
    for inv in Inventory.objects.filter(user=user, part=pi.part)
        ...
```

but I don't want to do a query for each ProjectItem.  I want to do:

```
project_items = ProjectItem.objects.filter(project=project,
                                           part__inventory__user=user)
```

but I don't know how to then pick up the Inventory objects that were matched in the query.

Any ideas?

edit: Let me clarify with an example.  Fix a `Project` A and a `User` cotton throughout.  Here are some tables (with `Project` and `User` omitted).

`ProjectItem`:

```
Part  Quantity
-----------------------
   X         2
   Y         1
```

`Inventory`:

```
Part  Stock  Location
---------------------
   X     91         S
   X     13         T
   Y     14         S
   Y    101         U
```

What I want (in table form) is:

```
Part Quantity Stock Location
------------------------------------
   X        2    91        S
   X        2    13        T
   Y        1    14        S
   Y        1   101        U
```

That is, I just want to join `ProjectItem` and `Inventory` along `part` and `user`.

edit 2: One possibility is to do two queries (objects, related objects) and do the join in Python as described here:

http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/

I wouldn't call this efficient compared to doing the join in the database, but it might be better than n+1 queries.

Comment: 1. What you have there is a [ManyToMany with extra data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). 2. Can you expand your question a little and add what you want your final result to look like? I'm having a hard time understanding the problem you are having...

Comment: Looking at the way you display, it looks like there's no way to escape a double loop. Forget about the query for a second, In your joined table you're going to have to have *some* duplication somewhere, you'll loop over all projectitems and then loop over all related inventory items... If there are many inventory items to the same projectitem, how is it displayed? Maybe what you *actually* want to do it filter on the Part object (which kind of connects everything)?

Comment: I tried to make a single example that is representative of a few different relationships I have in my application. I guess there are two cases: (1) The inventory is unique for each (user, part) pair.  In this case, there is no duplication.  I still don't see how to do that case.  (2) I want the duplication, but with iteration.  In this case, I conceptually want the for loop I wrote above, but I don't want the inner loop to hit the database for performance reasons.

Comment: So you need to use prefetche_related or select_related which prevents you hitting the database for further calls to the related models. Try figuring it out yourself (I'll add a solution with an example sometime later)

Answer (score 1):

```
prefetch_related(*lookups)
```

Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: You may also be interested in complex lookups with Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: prefetch_related expects a string, it cannot do complicated filtering like a QuerySet as your answer suggests (I also tested your solution and it doesn't work)

Comment: If anything, it should be `project_items = ProjectItem.objects.filter(project=project).prefetch_related('part__inventory_set__user')`

Comment: @yuvi Thanks for pointing out my string mistake. Glad we agree that prefetch_related is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use prefetch_related which is an expension to the select_related tool. Both of them are usefool tools to help you prevent multiple database hits when filtering on a related model.

> This is a performance booster which results in (sometimes much) larger
>   queries but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
>   database queries.
>   ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related))

prefetch_related is similar to select_related but uses pythonic (very reliably optimized) code to join different queries. In your case I think you have to use prefetch_related since you're going through a reverse relationship (from part to inventory). In code, that would look like this:

```
project_items = ProjectItem.objects.filter(project=project, part__inventory__user=user).prefetch_related('part__inventory_set')

for pi in project items:
    for pi.part.inventory_set.all():
        ...
```

It looks as though you are hitting the database every time, but when you use prefetch_related then django knows not to hit the database again when you call `pi.part.inventory_set.all()` but rather fetch it from the cache.

Important note - this isn't a magic function, it only works on `all()`. Using `pi.part.inventory_set.filter(...)` will cause additional queries, so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) which help you to retrieve any related data. such as

```
ProjectItem.objects.all().extra(select={'inventory__stock':'stock','inventory__location':'location'}).values('part', 'quantity', 'stock','location')
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks :)